# Fail a Mocha test when logger.error is called

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I want my tests to fail whenever there an error logged, and I do not want to repeat an expect clause for that in every test.

I stubbed my logger.error function, thinking I could just fail from within the stub.

Neither calling `assert.fail` nor throwing an `Error` causes the test to fail:

```
  loggerErrorStub = sinon.stub(Logger.prototype, 'error').callsFake((msg) => {
  console.log(`[[ERROR]] MSG: ${msg}`);
  assert.fail(`actual`, `expected`, `message`);
  throw new Error();
});
```

Calling either of these in the body of the `describe/it` clause works fine. So, I'm guessing the problem is, within the stub, Mocha is missing some context.

I could always add an `expect` clause at the end of the `it` such as `expect(loggerErrorStub).to.not.have.been.called`, but I want this to happen with ALL my tests, and do not want to repeat that line in every test.

Comment: Make sure the stub is being called within tests you want to fail.

Comment: It is called there @YuryTarabanko, but within other functions.
So `it` called `someFunction()` which, under some conditions calls `logger.error()` which reaches the stub.
To be explicit, the stub is reached from a code called withing the `it` context.

Comment: I mean. Are you sure that `logger.error` is your `loggerErrorStub`. For example `Logger` might do some context binding within its constructor `this.error = this.error.bind(this)` so by the time you stub `Logger.prototype.error` instance already has another method.

Comment: Understood @YuryTarabanko, but I see my stub being called instead of the regular `logger.error`

Comment: I see. It was just an idea of what might go wrong. :)